# Troubleshooting database performance issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I've a problem with database, and here is a scenario I'm dealing with every day: usually application can deal with traffic etc. but several times a day I'm dealing with performance issue. When it's happening stored procedures increase their execution time from 200%-1000% .
I have one, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585726/query-with-large-table-joins-optimization-techniques . Usually its execution takes about 6-8seconds (I've already optimized it from 20seconds cos at the beginning I thought the procedure is the culprit), but when **something** is happening, that procedure can execute even 60seconds.
And today I realized that there are more places in application that freeze, and what is more, I accidentaly realized that sample queries issued from SQL Management Studio, that usually execute in the blink of an eye, start to slow down when **something** happens with database server. Good news is, that thanks to this finding I eliminated both application & web servers as bottlenecks.
It's database server that's not able to handle requests. I wonder is there a way to troubleshoot live database and spot slow queries or other action like rebiulding indexes, statistics, memory problems etc. or perhaps other issues that could result in described performance decline?

Thanks, Pawel

Comment: Have you investigated locks? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yeap, we use NOLOCK basically everywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query that I use pretty much constantly.

It shows you **currently executing code**, **Wait information**, **blocking information, what spids are running, how long they have been running, what the current command is, what the query text is, and the xml query plan** if there is one in the cache:

```
SELECT 
d2.wait_type,
d1.session_id,
d2.blocking_session_id, 
d2.status,
d1.login_name,
d2.start_time, 
d2.command,
d3.[text] as Batch, 
SUBSTRING(d3.[text], (d2.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset 
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(d3.text)
        ELSE d2.statement_end_offset END 
            - d2.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS Current_Statement,
qp.query_plan,
d1.login_time, 
d2.wait_time,
d2.cpu_time, 
d1.memory_usage,
d2.total_elapsed_time, 
d2.reads,d2.writes,
d2.logical_reads
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions d1
JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests d2 ON d1.session_id=d2.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(d2.sql_handle) d3 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(d2.plan_handle) AS qp
WHERE d1.session_id <> @@SPID
```

Comment: I Appreciated! First thing to notice: I constantly get CXPACKET|62|0|suspended in for columns for slow query. I read about a bit about parallel query execution, but playing with that option (changing and disabling) didn't speed it up

Comment: `CXPACKET` isn't necessarily an indication of a problem in my experience - it just means you have one stream in a parallel process that is faster than another.  What I HAVE seen it indicate is out of date stats, which leads to bad query plans.  Have you run `sp_UpdateStats` or `UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN` on this/these DBs?

Comment: We follow default updates. I don't have "the power" to launch it though :)

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS if you right click on the Server name (not DB name) it will show you an Activity Monitor menu, click that and it would be a good place to start.